# How to use arrayformula to copy/paste rows en masse

Tags: google-sheets

I'm stress testing an application that relies on importing spreadsheets. I can populate those spreadsheets with dummy data, but sometimes I need thousands upon thousands of rows (the only thing that needs to change from one row to another is the email, where it can auto increment like so: user1, user2 etc).

I don't want to copy/paste 10,000 rows, I'd rather I have an arrayformula or something where I simply state: given the contents of row1, repeat X times and concatenate the user field by a number (I know how to do the last part, it's the publication of the rows number that I find difficult).

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ijUO8BIPM-ymfyTmZSbfyFd1it8Ijiu7uqDmMWX_DPE/edit#gid=0)
[image: Sample sheet]

### Script workaround

I wrote this quick Python script to do what I'm trying to do here using a spreadsheet formula:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv

with open("orders.csv", 'w') as myfile:
    header =["Site","Email","Password","Size","NotificationEmail","NotificationText","PostiveKW","NegativeKW","StyleNumber","EarlyLinkMonitorKeywords","NewPageMonitorKeywords","FirstNameBilling","LastNameBilling","address1Billing","address2Billing","cityBilling","stateBilling","zipCodeBilling","countryBilling","phoneBilling","houseNbBilling","FirstNameShipping","LastNameShipping","address1Shipping","address2Shipping","cityShipping","stateShipping","zipCodeShipping","countryShipping","phoneShipping","houseNbShipping","friendlyName","NameOnCard","DOB","cardType","CardNumber","CardExpirationMonth","CardExpirationYear","CardSecurityCode","billingEmail","paypalEmail","paypalPassword","CheckoutDelaySeconds","CheckoutOncePerWebsite","OrderThreads"]

    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(header)

    numberOfRows = 10
    while numberOfRows > 0:
        row=["StressTest","guest.805642","guest","3","","","xxx","","","http://www.footaction.com/product/model:95404/sku:23419012/jordan-6-rings-boys-grade-school/black/white/","","Mark","Escude","105 Putney bridge lane","","Simpsonville","SC","29681","US","9018345575","","Mark","Escude","105 Putney bridge lane","","Simpsonville","SC","29681","US","9018345575","","6676","Mark Escude","0/0/0","AMEX","3.71E+14","1","2020","562","Escudem@mac.com","","","0","FALSE","100"]
        numberOfRows = numberOfRows-1

        wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: sample sheet provided

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**A3:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(ROW(A1:A4),"Select '"& JOIN("",IF(ISBLANK(A2:AS2),"-",A2:AS2))&"' label '"& JOIN("",IF(ISBLANK(A2:AS2),"-",A2:AS2))&"' '' ",0),"",1))
```

We're inputting a blank array `ROW (A1:A4)` of size 4 rows. And we're using `QUERY` literals to repeat B2:AS2 4 times.

***EDIT:***

Formula Simplification #3

Comment: this is not clear.. so what is it that i'm querying from? suppose the only row of Data i have is in Sheet1!A1:Y1

Comment: @abbood, If you want to repeat 10 times, Change ROW(A1:A4) to `ROW (A1:A10)` That's all.

Comment: again i'm not sure what i'm copying from.. perhaps if you make a copy of the above sample sheet and use your script above to demonstrate, that would eliminate all the guesswork

Comment: @abbood Just copy my formula and paste it in A3. You'll get it

Comment: @pnuts No. That's the modification op has to make/ had already made. " **the only thing**  *that needs to change from one row to another is the email, where it can auto increment like so: user1, user2 etc).*.... *concatenate the user field by a number* (**I know how to do the last part**, *it's the publication of the rows number that i find difficult).* " So, He would need to skip the email column and enter his formula( that he already made) in there, while filling the rest with my formula.

Answer (score 1):

A much much simpler answer:

A3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A4)=2:2,"",2:2))
```

2:2 will be the array to copy.